# Bogus faked strings length in range between values

Tags: c#, faker, bogus

Im writing rule for my string property generated by Bogus:

```
var fakeThings= new Faker<Thing>()
   .RuleFor(x => x.Name, f => f.Company.CompanyName());
```

How to generate string property in `Bogus` between specified values? Something like:

```
.RuleFor(x => x.Name, f => f.Company.CompanyName().Length(1, 30);
// returns CompanyName with min 1 char and max 30 chars
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on which version you are using, really. I would suggest you try [String2](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/blob/b9049abf8b40203c09079741bcb328da95899f81/Source/Bogus/Randomizer.cs#L387) or [Utf16String](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/blob/b9049abf8b40203c09079741bcb328da95899f81/Source/Bogus/Randomizer.cs#L400) depending on your desired character set.

```
.RuleFor(x => x.Name, f => f.Random.String2(1, 30);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the `.ClampLength(min, max)` extension method for any `string`. Eg:

```cs
using Bogus.Extensions;

.RuleFor(x => x.Name, f => f.Company.CompanyName().ClampLength(1, 30));
```